# PHP calling static class method in a closure defined in another method

Tags: php

I'm trying to create an application that runs in parallel. For this i am using php PECL extension `parallel`.
This works, however, method `runtest` is called inside the closure `$task`, doesn't work. So its more like I am missing something inside closure.

```
Class A {
    
    public function main(){
        $threadCount = 10;

        $task = function($i) {
            echo "Running thread $i\n";
            self::runtest($i); // <--- This doesn't work
            echo "Write complete\n";
        };

        $runtimeList = [];
        for($i=0; $i<$threadCount; $i++){
            $runtimeList[] = new \parallel\Runtime();
        }

        $futureList = [];            
        foreach($runtimeList as $i => $runtime){
            $futureList[] = $runtime->run($task, [$i]);
        }

        do{
            usleep(1);
            $allDone = array_reduce(
                $futureList,
                function ($c, $future): bool {
                    return $c && $future->done();
                },
                true
            );
        }while( false === $allDone);

        echo "done\n";
    }


    private static function runtest($i){
        $msg = "The thread ".$i." wrote this line\n";

        file_put_contents("E:/logs/test.txt", $msg, FILE_APPEND);

        //file path are correct
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a small change to get it working:

Add this above your $task closure function:

```
$fn_callable = ['A','runtest'];
```

Change your $task closure function to the following:

```
$task = function($i) use($fn_callable) {
    echo "Running thread $i\n";
    $fn_callable($i);
    echo "Write complete\n";
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, unfortunately this didn't work.

Comment: Maybe try changing the private static to public static?

Comment: That didn't work either.